# Convert an integer into a bitlist

Tags: python

Imagine I have the following bitlist in Python.

```
mylist = {1:"Error 1", 
          2:"Error 2",
          4:"Error 3",
          8:"Error 4",
          16:"Error 5",
          ...
          n:"Error n"}
```

Then I have a devices which sends me a bitlist of current errors. When bit 0 is set, Error 1 occured. When bit 4 (binary 10000 -> decimal 16) is set, error 5 occured.
But then there could also be multiple errors.
For example the device can send `7`.  Now I need a function which returns me something like `["Error 1", "Error2", "Error 3"]`

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Why you want `["Error 1", "Error2", "Error 3"]` for number 7 is there any logic behind this? and did you have tried any thing so far?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I made a mistake in my sourcecode. I'm going to fix this.

Comment: @0xAffe so you check the digit with mylist and send all the value list the digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit:* ok, now your code uses the already-shifted numbers as I said... then it's even easier:

```
def bitToDesc(b):
    return [v for k,v in mylist.iteritems() if k & b]
```

Comment: Wow, this is why I love python. Doing such suchs in a single line is awesome. It works perfeclty. Now I'll try to understand what's happening. Thank you!